# FullCalendar JS - Styling issue on TimeGrid

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm using the FullCalendar plugin: https://fullcalendar.io/

For some reason when loading the time grid view the title doesn't cut off correctly as seen in the screenshot below

[image: https://fullcalendar.io/]

Below is the code to initialize the calendar

```
 function SetupAndRenderCalendar() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        height: 'parent',
        plugins: ['dayGrid', 'timeGrid'],
        defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
        header: { center: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek' },
        minTime: "06:00:00",
        maxTime: "20:00:00",

    });

    calendar.render();
}
```

I've seen some StackOverflow posts that advises to give the css class a custom override  like so

```
<style>
.fc-time-grid-event {
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
</style>
```

Honestly, I didn't like this solution as didn't wrap the text nicely when the event div was big enough.

I've checked the demos on the site and there's no issue with the wrapping when there's a long Title, so it must be a bug on my side.

So the question is, what am I doing wrong and how do I get the Title to wrap correctly?

Comment: From the screenshot it looks like you may have some custom CSS in your page (either via a fullCalendar theme, or alterations to the fullCalendar CSS files, or some extra CSS you've added yourself)? Or have you done anything to customise the appearance of your events via the `eventRender` callback? Those things are by far the most likely cause of an issue like that. I note that the events also appear in slightly the wrong place in the grid, which is another symptom of CSS issues. Strip it back to the original default CSS provided by fullCalendar and see if you still have an issue.

Comment: Great tip! Going to try that now to see if there's some higher level custom css on the layout page causing the issue.

Comment: @ADyson you were correct. The issue is that the project uses a Metronic theme which overrides the default behavior and is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per ADyson's comment, there was something happening on higher lever with the CSS.

What happenend was that we used a store bought theme (Metronic) that had custom css for the look of FullCalendar.

I then added the below code to the custom css and it fixed the problem.

```
.fc-time-grid-event .fc-content {
overflow: hidden;
max-height: 100%;
```

}

Not sure this will help someone else, but you never know.